# Не получается отформатировать диск через установку windows

Tags: windows, установка

Не получается отформатировать диск через установку windows (кнопка отформатировать неактивная)

[image: фото]

Из-за того,что диск fat32, а не ntfs
Что делать? Как форматировать?

Answer (score 3):

Не надо его форматировать. Этот раздел на 286 МБ нужен для загрузчика системы. Форматировать надо следующий.

Comment: 286 мегабайтов для загрузчика системы? Многовато. Но, действительно, мало для установки Windows 10.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov, win7 отбивала 100 метров, 8 уже 200. 10 отбивает 400-500. Так что скорее всего у ОП была на винте 8, а потом он решил всё переустановить.

Comment: @donRumata Под Boot Area Windows, начиная с Windows Vista, выделяет отдельный раздел 100М. Тогда же ОС опционально стала создавать разделы восстановления (размер варьируется в зависимости от ОС, на Windows 10 Pro x64 это около 450М), размещая их после System Area на физическом носителе. Начиная с Windows 8 создание раздела восстановления включено по умолчанию, хотя до сих пор отключаемо.  Но Boot Area до сих пор имеет размер 100М: на всех моих домашних компьютерах (2xWindows 10,2x Windows 7) и рабочих - это так. Поэтому у меня и вызывает недоумение странный размер первого раздела.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov, хзхз, у нас 10 после установки поверх 7, САМА отбивает раздел на ~450 метров. Хотя до этого разметку создавали руками под свои нужды. Могу как-нить скрин скинуть.

Comment: @donRumata Скидывайте, интересно: я просмотрел с пару десятков машин на работе, ни разу не встретил Boot Area > 100M. P.S. Большая часть машина с Windows 10 - это как раз установленные поверх Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

Второй раздел тоже нельзя форматировать? На скриншоте плохо видно, разрешена ли кнопка "Удалить" или нет. Если разрешена, удалите раздел (все равно ведь хотите форматировать), затем выделяйте освободившееся место, установщик всё сам далее сделает.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/237841)

Comment: @Sublihim Да? Тогда ответьте мне, пожалуйста, что является ответов на вопрос? Решение - предложено!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй сначала разметить диск через [Gparted Live](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/files/gparted-live-stable/), а потом уже на заранее созданные разделы ставь windows.